# Problem in Django Testing with Selenium ( TypeError : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType )

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, testing

I am currently running a testing to check whether there is any problem with client-side rendering in Django. Therefore, I am running a loop to visit every route available in the Django project and record the browser console.

The code is as follows :

```py
class SeleniumTest2(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super(MySeleniumTests, self).setUp()
        User = get_user_model()
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_superuser('superuser', 'superuser@example.com', 'password')
        self.client.login(username='superuser', password='password')
        models = apps.get_models()
        factories = generate_dynamic_factories_2(models)
        for model_name, factory_class in factories.items():
            instances = factory_class.create_batch(10)
            for instance in instances :
                instance.save()

    def tearDown(self):
            self.selenium.quit()
            super(MySeleniumTests, self).tearDown()
            
    if(check_library_selenium()):
        def test_client_side(self):
            urls = get_urls()
            driver = webdriver.Edge()
            live_server = self.live_server_url
            for url in urls:
                driver.get( str(live_server) + url)
                # Print or use the console output as needed
                logs = driver.get_log('browser')
                print(url, logs)
            driver.quit()
    else :
        print(RED+'Client-side checker skipped'+RESET)
```

And the error is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/Desktop/Fathi/test-6/reporter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "/Users/zulfathihanafi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I did try to do the checking if the `live_server_url` is available or not :

```py
def test_client_side(self):
    urls = get_urls()
    driver = webdriver.Edge()
    for url in urls:
        # Check if the live server URL is None
        if self.live_server_url is None:
            raise Exception('The live server URL is None.')

        driver.get(self.live_server_url + url)
        # Print or use the console output as needed
        logs = driver.get_log('browser')
        print(url, logs)
    driver.quit()
```

But I ended up with the same result.